# Using Socket.io to emit and receive messages on the client

Tags: sockets, websocket, socket.io

So I am using socket.io to send messages back and forth.

I would like to use the socket to raise events and catch them within the client itself. So far, I have tried (in chrome console i.e. client):

```
socket.on('news', function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

But, when I ran the following (from my chrome console):

> socket.emit('news', {my: 'data'});

I did not get a console.log message.

Could anyone please help me achieve the desired result ?

Answer (score 1):

The code below:

```
socket.on('news', function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

runs in your server application so you should see them in your `cmd` (windows) instead of the browser. Just to be safe hard code the `socket.emit('news', {my: 'data'});` in your client application/script if you can't still see the log in your terminal. Socket.io might not be available in the `window` if you do it that way.

If you want to raise event and catch them within the client, you can do this:

Server:

```
socket.on('news', function(data){
    var msg = data + 'world';
    socket.emit('news-response', msg);

});
```

Client:

```
socket.emit('news', 'hello');

socket.on('news-response', function(data){
    console.log(data);   //should output 'hello world'
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I want to know, how can I have `socket.on` or something similar, running in the client itself ?

Comment: `socket.on('news', function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});`

will work in the client side if you are expecting a `socket.emit('news', {val : 'val'})` from your server. It does work in reverse.

Then you should see a message (whatever `data` contains) in the console of your browser.

Comment: How can I have both working in the `client` itself ? Like a pubsub within the client..

Comment: No you can't. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Raise and listen to custom events on the client :)

Comment: +1. Thanks for your time. I thought about this method. But I am trying to avoid the round-trip from the server. I guess its not possible in the current socket.io version (1.2.0)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65247/discussion-between-javiniar-leonard-and-myusuf).